# htaccess to redirect both folder and file name

Tags: .htaccess, directory, filenames

I have a file in a folder like this `folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.htm`. I also have another file like this `folder1/folder2/folder3-filename.htm`. When i browse the url `mysite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.htm`, i want the `folder3-filename.htm` will be served (displayed)

I know some basics about file name rewrite rules, but i have not seen any mixed-up combination of folder name and file name in that way.

Could anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: Does `folder3` change, or is it a static value?

Comment: it changes, that is any folder name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the expression `[^/]+` to match all characters up to but not including the the next `/` and then `.+` to match everything after the last `/`, the following will work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/([^/]+)/(.+)$ folder1/folder2/$1-$2 [L]
```